# How to find all generators for a cyclic group of order $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let us say I have to find all the generators for modulo $p=7$. That must mean that:

$$\mathbb{Z}_7 = \mathbb{Z}^*_7 = \{1,2,...,7-1\}$$

So now I need to get all the generators for $7$. Now I choose randomly from the group $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and pick the number $3$. So if $3^n$ for $n = \{1,2,\dotsc,7-1\}$ can generate all elements from $\mathbb{Z}_7$, the number is considered a generator.

$$3^1 \pmod 7\equiv 3\\
3^2 \pmod 7\equiv 2\\
3^3 \pmod 7\equiv 6\\
3^4 \pmod 7\equiv 4\\
3^5 \pmod 7\equiv 5\\
3^6 \pmod 7\equiv 1$$

Now I have found one generator. Someone claimed one can find all generators in the group with a faster method, when one already has one generator. Can someone please show me how that works?

Comment: How can $\Bbb Z_7$ be the same as $\Bbb Z_7^*$?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Your question is not really clear. Are you finding a method to discover all the generator of $\mathbb Z_7^*$ having found a generator of this group?

Comment: @Bernard hi, I always thought they were the same? Aren't they the same?

Comment: @Menezio hi, I'm just trying to find all the generators in the cyclic group as fast as possible. I've read a lot of different things online, but I would just love when someone could go through my example and explain how they find the generators. The fastest method I have found is when you find a generator and then, so it is claimed online, it is easy to find all the other elements. KR

Comment: No: the first is the field with $7$ elements, the other is its set of units (non-zero elements). Only the latter is a multiplicative group, and it has order $6$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that $\mathbb Z_7^*$ is a group with multiplication, and it is cyclic with generator the element $3$ as you show. To find the other generators you can do this: since $\mathbb Z_7$ has got six elements and it is cyclic, then it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_6$ and the isomorphism is the following (try to show this as exercise):
\begin{equation}
\varphi:(\mathbb Z_6,+) \longrightarrow (\mathbb Z_7^*, \cdot), \quad i\longmapsto 3^i
\end{equation}
Now, since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, it maps generators in generators (and vice-versa). The generators of $\mathbb Z_6$ are just $1$ and $5$ (numbers coprime with $6$ smaller than $6$), so the generators of $\mathbb Z_7^*$ are $\varphi(1)=3^1=3$ and $\varphi(5)=3^5=5$ modulo $7$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand it! Last question: it is the correct way I find the first generator (the three) which you use to calculate 3 and 5? Or is there a faster method?

Comment: I don't know a general method to find the first generator, so it is ok what you have done

Answer (score 8):

Here it is: in a cyclic group of order $n$, with generator $a$, all subgroups are cyclic, generated (by definition) by some $a^k$, and the order of $a^k$ is equal to
$$\frac n{\gcd(n,k)}.$$
Therefore $a^k$ is another generator of the group if and only if $k$ is coprime to $n$.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So I find the co-primes to three that are elements of the cyclic group? Which in this case would be 2, 4, 5? And then I say 7/gcd(7,2), 7/gcd(7,4) and 7/gcd(7,5)? And the result(s) will be the other generators?

Comment: No quite: the exponents which are coprime to $6$. This makes much less. Further, it is very long to check, you indeed obtain generators.