# Finding the elements with order $30$ in group $\mathbb Z^*_{31}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups

The elements of the group $\mathbb Z^*_{31}$ is $1$ to $30$. I found the first element with order $30$ is $11$ by checking the powers of each element by $2,3,5,6,10,15,30$. My professor mentioned that the other elements with order $30$ can be found after finding the first element using a theorem. Could someone please help me with that.

Comment: You needed to check only $6, 10, $ and $15$, not $2, 3, $ and $5$

Comment: Hi and welcome! I think you can find the answer to your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3605577/how-to-find-all-generators-for-a-cyclic-group-of-order-n/3605604#3605604)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner , Could you please explain why not 2,3 and 5. Because, i found the order of 2 in the group as 5 (2^5 = 1(mod 31). perhaps, you mean for the elements after 11?

Comment: you would have found $2$ not to be a primitive root when you checked $2^{15}$

Comment: @J.W Tanner Yes.Understood. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to find all other elements of order $30$, once you find one element of order $30$. This is because $31$ is a prime number so $\mathbb{Z}_{31}^{*}$ is cyclic, and once you have found a generator, say $g$, you can find all other elements. The theorem you need to use is that $|g^{s}| = \frac{|g|}{(s,|g|)}$, where $|\cdot|$ denote the order of an element. Then all elements of the form $g^{s}$, with $(s,|g|) = (s,30) = 1$, will have order $30$ by the theorem. After doing the computation, you get the set:
$$
\{ 11^1, 11^7 , 11^{11}, 11^{13}, 11^{17} , 11^{19} , 11^{23}, 11^{29} \} = \{ 11 ,   13 ,   24  ,  21   ,  3  ,  22  ,  12    , 17\} \pmod{31}
$$

Comment: $24 \equiv 11^{11} \pmod{31}$ , and $22 \equiv 11^{19} \pmod{31}$.

Comment: No, those are exponents of the generator.

Comment: I'm sorry.  Under the isomorphism you would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Welcome! You've found that every element in $(\mathbf Z/31\mathbf Z)^\times$ is a power of $11$.

Now, if an element $a$ in a group has order $n$, $a^k$ has order $\;\dfrac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$.